# The sum of three positive integers is $20$. Find the probability that they form the sides of a triangle.

Tags: probability, permutations

> The sum of three positive integers is $20$. Find the probability that they form the sides of a triangle.

Let $a,b,c$ be there positive integers. So, $a+b+c=20$

Total number of solutions would be $^{19}C_2=171$

For $a,b,c$ to form a triangle $0\lt a,b,c\le9$

So, number of such solutions= coefficient of $x^{20}$ in $(x+x^2+x^3+...+x^9)^3=$ coefficient of $x^{17}$ in $(1+x+x^2+...+x^8)^3=$ coefficient of $x^{17}$ in $(1-x^9)^3(1-x)^{-3}=1\times^{19}C_2-3\times^{10}C_2=36$

So, the required probability is $\frac{36}{171}$ but the answer given is $\frac8{33}$

In the hint, they have written total combinations of $a,b,c=\frac{144}{6}+\frac{27}{3}=33$, and favorable combinations of $a,b,c=\frac{12}{3}+\frac{24}{6}=8$

I think they have split $171$ as $144+27$ and $36$ as $24+12$ but why? and why to divide them with $6$ or $3$?

Comment: What about the sum of any two sides being greater than the third side ?

Comment: @true blue anil, isn't that covered when we take $0\lt a, b, c\le9$?

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that !

Answer (score 3):

It is a bad question as they have not described how the sides have been chosen, but their answer almost reveals what they intended:

- There are $171$ compositions of $20$ into three positive integer parts (any order).  Of these,

  - $144$ compositions have the three parts distinct
  - $27$ compositions have two of the parts equal and the third distinct
  - $0$ compositions have all three parts equal ($20$ is not divisible by $3$)
- So removing duplicates which are the same but in a different order, there are

  - $\frac{144}{3!}=24$ partitions which have the three parts distinct
  - $\frac{27}{3}=9$ partitions which have two of the parts equal and the third distinct
  - $0$ partitions have all three parts equal ($20$ is not divisible by $3$)
  - making $24+9+0=33$ for the number of partitions of $20$ into three positive integer parts

The $36 \to 8$ is the same but where the two smaller numbers add up to more than the largest number

Comment: Thanks, how did the number $144$ come about?

Comment: @aarbee - I do not know how they did it, but the easiest numbers to find here are $171,9,0$ and you can say $171- 3\times 9 -1\times 0=144$, easily extended to other cases.  Before you ask, $9$ comes from counting $1+1+18, 2+2+16,\ldots, 9+9+2$ and spotting these is no triplet

Comment: Thanks. Now I am trying to see why they split $36=12+24$. Of course, we can't use $1+1+18$, etc here. If I assume the two values were same, then the third would have $9$ options? I guess not.

Comment: @aarbee perhaps say the third has to leave a positive even number so must on of $2,4,\ldots,18$ so $9$ and $3\times 9$ possibilities.  Of these, $6,7,8,9$ would make a triangle so $4$ and $3 \times 4=12$ possibilities

Comment: That's quite a reasonable explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the case of a triangle's sides, order has no meaning. The set $\{7,8,5\}$, representing $a,b$ and $c$ forms the same triangle as $\{8,5,7\}$ and likewise. So, if $a,b,c$ are distinct, the $6$ possible ordered pairs give only $1$ combination, hence division by $6$. If two of $a,b,c$ are equal, then $3$ different ordered pairs are possible, which give only one combination, hence division by $3$.

Comment: This is certainly what the person who wrote the answer was thinking, but I'm not so sure it's clear from the question, which I think is badly posed.  The question should specify whether the probability space is sets of $3$ positive integers or ordered triples of $3$ positive integers.

Comment: Thanks and how to decide the split? $171=144+27$. Why so?

Comment: There are $144$ distinct combinations. I feel the easiest way to get this would be to take the other case, the one where two of the three are equal. Say $a=b\neq c$. Then, we have the cases of $a=b=1$, $a=b=2$,...$a=b=9$ that is $9$ cases. We would similarly have $9$ cases each for $b=c\neq a$ and $a=c\neq b$. That makes $27$. Hence the distinct case would have $171-27=144$ solutions. Note that there is never any case of an equilateral triangle.